# Syntax for passing parameters in HTTP POST Request

Tags: http, post, vb6

Right now I have a working POC API that returns a product based on a product id. I can test the API successfully using Swagger. My VB6 code is as follows:

```
Public Function WebRequestPost(sUrl As String) As String
    Dim xmlhttp As MSXML2.xmlhttp

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.open "POST", sUrl, False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp.send "{""id"":2}"
    WebRequestPost = xmlhttp.responseText

    Set xmlhttp = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim result As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim productId As String

    url = "http://localhost:1112/api/Products"
    result = WebRequestPost(url)

    MsgBox result

End Sub
```

I have used similar code with the GET method and passing the parameter through the URL with success, but I can't seem to get the POST method working. I have a feeling it lies in the xmlhttp.send method.

Comment: The problem is not `send` but what you are sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by reformatting:

`xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

to

`xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"`

and passing the payload in the form of: `xmlhttp.send 2`

Which was made into a variable passed into the parameter in the form of `xmlhttp.send sId`

Ultimately ending up with:

```
Public Function WebRequestPost(sUrl As String, sId As Integer) As String
    Dim xmlhttp As MSXML2.xmlhttp

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.open "POST", sUrl, False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    xmlhttp.send sId
    WebRequestPost = xmlhttp.responseText

    Set xmlhttp = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim result As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim productId As String

    url = "http://localhost:1112/api/products"
    result = WebRequestPost(url, 3)

    MsgBox result

End Sub
```